# The proof of $\overline{\{a_k\}}\subset \{a\}$. Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a metric space. Let $\overline{}$ mean the closure and $N$ mean the neighborhood.

Suppose that the sequence $A=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges to $a$.

Then, I proved that $\overline{A}\subset \{a \}$ but this cannot hold so I must have made a mistake.

---

Let $y\in \overline A.$

From the definition of the closure, for each $k\in \mathbb N$, $N(y, \frac{1}{k})\cap A\neq \emptyset.$ Then, there exists $b_k$ s.t. $b_k\in N(y, \frac{1}{k})\cap A.$ Since $b_k\in A,$ there exists $j_k\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $b_k=a_{j_k}$, and since $b_k \in N(y,\frac{1}{k})$, $d(b_k, y)<\frac{1}{k}$.

Letting $k\to \infty,$ I get $\lim d(b_k, y)=d(\lim b_k,y)=d(\lim a_{j_k},y)=d(a, y)=0.$ Thus $y=a.$

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What if $b_k=y$ for all $k?$

Answer (score 1):

What if $j_k \not\to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

You can only show that $A \cup \{a\} = \overline{A}$. Go for that instead.

$a \in \overline{A}$ is easy from the convergence. And $A \subseteq
\overline{A}$ always holds, for all $A$.

So assume $y$ is in $\overline{A}$ but $y \neq a_k$ for all $k$ then you can easily ensure that the $j_k$ tend to infinity as $k$ gets larger. (Why?)
Then $y=a$ follows by unicity of limits. Done.

Comment: I don't know why I can do $k\to \infty \Rightarrow j_k\to \infty$ ; Probably I should use the supposition $y\neq a_k$ for all $k$, but I don't know how. @Henno_Brandsma

Comment: @L-20 Pick $a_{j_1} \in B(y,\frac11)$. Once you have defined $j_k$ define $j_{k+1}=\min\{n > j_k: a_n \in B(y,\frac{1}{k+1})\}$ which is well-defined as the set we take the min of is non-empty.